# Import JSON file with operations

Tags: json, python-3.x

In my JSON file, I have the following entry

```
{
    "a": "2 * 3",
}
```

I want to import this file with Python 3.6 in a dictionary where key "a" is the integer 6. How can I "execute" the string  "2 * 3" during the import ?

Comment: You probably need `eval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can use `eval` in your case

**Ex:**

```
import ast

raw_string = """{
    "a": "2 * 3"
}"""

data = ast.literal_eval(raw_string)
data = {k: eval(v) for k, v in data.items()}

print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 6}
```